# How to make hover on two div at once?

Tags: html, css

I need to make an hover effect like this. So that when hovering over one block, the hover fills two blocks within one.
 [image]

They are located in different div, I tried add hover on sidebar class, it fills the entire div. 
It`s my code:

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 245px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.side-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    width: 176px;
    height: 392px;
    top: 178px;
    left: 24px;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.sidebar-link:hover,  .sidebar-link.is-active {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #6c5ecf;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 216px;
    height: 56px;
  }
  .sidebar.collapse {
    width: 90px;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  }
  .side-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 176px;
    height: 392px;
  }
  .sidebar-link{
    display: flex;
    width: 176px;
    height: 56px;
  } 
  .side-menu a {
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000 ;/* var(--body-color); */
    
  }
  .side-menu a + a {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .side-menu svg {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: var(--button-bg);
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
  .side-menu svg:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #32a7e2;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
            <div class="side-wrapper">
                <div class="side-menu ">
                <a class="sidebar-link discover is-active" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path d="M9.135 20.773v-3.057c0-.78.637-1.414 1.423-1.414h2.875c.377 0 .74.15 1.006.414.267.265.417.625.417 1v3.057c-.002.325.126.637.356.867.23.23.544.36.87.36h1.962a3.46 3.46 0 002.443-1 3.41 3.41 0 001.013-2.422V9.867c0-.735-.328-1.431-.895-1.902l-6.671-5.29a3.097 3.097 0 00-3.949.072L3.467 7.965A2.474 2.474 0 002.5 9.867v8.702C2.5 20.464 4.047 22 5.956 22h1.916c.68 0 1.231-.544 1.236-1.218l.027-.009z" />
                    </svg>
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="sidebar-link trending" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.835 12.007l.002.354c.012 1.404.096 2.657.242 3.451 0 .015.16.802.261 1.064.16.38.447.701.809.905a2 2 0 00.91.219c.249-.012.66-.137.954-.242l.244-.094c1.617-.642 4.707-2.74 5.891-4.024l.087-.09.39-.42c.245-.322.375-.715.375-1.138 0-.379-.116-.758-.347-1.064-.07-.099-.18-.226-.28-.334l-.379-.397c-1.305-1.321-4.129-3.175-5.593-3.79 0-.013-.91-.393-1.343-.407h-.057c-.665 0-1.286.379-1.603.991-.087.168-.17.496-.233.784l-.114.544c-.13.874-.216 2.216-.216 3.688zm-6.332-1.525C3.673 10.482 3 11.162 3 12a1.51 1.51 0 001.503 1.518l3.7-.328c.65 0 1.179-.532 1.179-1.19 0-.658-.528-1.191-1.18-1.191l-3.699-.327z" />
                    </svg>
                    My Courses
                </a>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

stackoverflow asks me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I don't know what details to add
I hope someone will be able to help

Comment: I can't really follow what the exact issue is, but using `.sidebar-link:hover` Both the svg and the link is getting the correct background color?

Comment: What does this mean?: "So that when hovering over one block, the hover fills two blocks within one."

Comment: replacing  `.side-menu svg:hover` with `.side-menu:hover > *` would highlight both blocks when the menu div is hovered (although it's not clear this is what's desired).

Comment: Put the two divs in a container/wrapper div and then put the hover styles on that container div.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question again and I think you don't need 'an extra box'. You can use padding and border-radius values the get the desired effect.

See demo below.

```css
.side-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.sidebar-link:hover,  .sidebar-link.is-active {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #2f3ced;
    border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
    width: 216px;
    height: 56px;
  }

  .side-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px; /* for demo */
    border-left: 10px solid #3f8cff;
  }
  .sidebar-link{
    display: flex;
    width: 176px;
    height: 56px;
  } 
  .side-menu a {
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 20px;
    
  }
  .side-menu a + a {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .side-menu svg {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: var(--button-bg);
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
  .side-menu svg:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2f3ced;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
            <div class="side-wrapper">
                <div class="side-menu ">
                <a class="sidebar-link discover is-active" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path d="M9.135 20.773v-3.057c0-.78.637-1.414 1.423-1.414h2.875c.377 0 .74.15 1.006.414.267.265.417.625.417 1v3.057c-.002.325.126.637.356.867.23.23.544.36.87.36h1.962a3.46 3.46 0 002.443-1 3.41 3.41 0 001.013-2.422V9.867c0-.735-.328-1.431-.895-1.902l-6.671-5.29a3.097 3.097 0 00-3.949.072L3.467 7.965A2.474 2.474 0 002.5 9.867v8.702C2.5 20.464 4.047 22 5.956 22h1.916c.68 0 1.231-.544 1.236-1.218l.027-.009z" />
                    </svg>
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="sidebar-link trending" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.835 12.007l.002.354c.012 1.404.096 2.657.242 3.451 0 .015.16.802.261 1.064.16.38.447.701.809.905a2 2 0 00.91.219c.249-.012.66-.137.954-.242l.244-.094c1.617-.642 4.707-2.74 5.891-4.024l.087-.09.39-.42c.245-.322.375-.715.375-1.138 0-.379-.116-.758-.347-1.064-.07-.099-.18-.226-.28-.334l-.379-.397c-1.305-1.321-4.129-3.175-5.593-3.79 0-.013-.91-.393-1.343-.407h-.057c-.665 0-1.286.379-1.603.991-.087.168-.17.496-.233.784l-.114.544c-.13.874-.216 2.216-.216 3.688zm-6.332-1.525C3.673 10.482 3 11.162 3 12a1.51 1.51 0 001.503 1.518l3.7-.328c.65 0 1.179-.532 1.179-1.19 0-.658-.528-1.191-1.18-1.191l-3.699-.327z" />
                    </svg>
                    My Courses
                </a>
                                <a class="sidebar-link trending" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.835 12.007l.002.354c.012 1.404.096 2.657.242 3.451 0 .015.16.802.261 1.064.16.38.447.701.809.905a2 2 0 00.91.219c.249-.012.66-.137.954-.242l.244-.094c1.617-.642 4.707-2.74 5.891-4.024l.087-.09.39-.42c.245-.322.375-.715.375-1.138 0-.379-.116-.758-.347-1.064-.07-.099-.18-.226-.28-.334l-.379-.397c-1.305-1.321-4.129-3.175-5.593-3.79 0-.013-.91-.393-1.343-.407h-.057c-.665 0-1.286.379-1.603.991-.087.168-.17.496-.233.784l-.114.544c-.13.874-.216 2.216-.216 3.688zm-6.332-1.525C3.673 10.482 3 11.162 3 12a1.51 1.51 0 001.503 1.518l3.7-.328c.65 0 1.179-.532 1.179-1.19 0-.658-.528-1.191-1.18-1.191l-3.699-.327z" />
                    </svg>
                    My Courses
                </a>
                                <a class="sidebar-link trending" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.835 12.007l.002.354c.012 1.404.096 2.657.242 3.451 0 .015.16.802.261 1.064.16.38.447.701.809.905a2 2 0 00.91.219c.249-.012.66-.137.954-.242l.244-.094c1.617-.642 4.707-2.74 5.891-4.024l.087-.09.39-.42c.245-.322.375-.715.375-1.138 0-.379-.116-.758-.347-1.064-.07-.099-.18-.226-.28-.334l-.379-.397c-1.305-1.321-4.129-3.175-5.593-3.79 0-.013-.91-.393-1.343-.407h-.057c-.665 0-1.286.379-1.603.991-.087.168-.17.496-.233.784l-.114.544c-.13.874-.216 2.216-.216 3.688zm-6.332-1.525C3.673 10.482 3 11.162 3 12a1.51 1.51 0 001.503 1.518l3.7-.328c.65 0 1.179-.532 1.179-1.19 0-.658-.528-1.191-1.18-1.191l-3.699-.327z" />
                    </svg>
                    My Courses
                </a>
                                <a class="sidebar-link trending" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.835 12.007l.002.354c.012 1.404.096 2.657.242 3.451 0 .015.16.802.261 1.064.16.38.447.701.809.905a2 2 0 00.91.219c.249-.012.66-.137.954-.242l.244-.094c1.617-.642 4.707-2.74 5.891-4.024l.087-.09.39-.42c.245-.322.375-.715.375-1.138 0-.379-.116-.758-.347-1.064-.07-.099-.18-.226-.28-.334l-.379-.397c-1.305-1.321-4.129-3.175-5.593-3.79 0-.013-.91-.393-1.343-.407h-.057c-.665 0-1.286.379-1.603.991-.087.168-.17.496-.233.784l-.114.544c-.13.874-.216 2.216-.216 3.688zm-6.332-1.525C3.673 10.482 3 11.162 3 12a1.51 1.51 0 001.503 1.518l3.7-.328c.65 0 1.179-.532 1.179-1.19 0-.658-.528-1.191-1.18-1.191l-3.699-.327z" />
                    </svg>
                    My Courses
                </a>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the hover selector to one level above: `.sidebar-link:hover` and then modify states of its child elements (the svg and the text).
(I assumed you wanted the same thing for the selected item, so I used `.sidebar-link:hover svg, .sidebar-link.is-active svg` to select the svg)

See here:

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 245px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.side-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 176px;
    height: 392px;
    top: 178px;
    left: 24px;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.sidebar-link:hover,  .sidebar-link.is-active {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #6c5ecf;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 216px;
    height: 56px;
  }
  .sidebar.collapse {
    width: 90px;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  }
  .side-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 176px;
    height: 392px;
  }
  .sidebar-link{
    display: flex;
    width: 176px;
    height: 56px;
  } 
  .side-menu a {
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000 ;/* var(--body-color); */
    
  }
  .side-menu a + a {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .side-menu svg {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: var(--button-bg);
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
  .sidebar-link:hover svg, .sidebar-link.is-active svg {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #32a7e2;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
            <div class="side-wrapper">
                <div class="side-menu ">
                <a class="sidebar-link discover is-active" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path d="M9.135 20.773v-3.057c0-.78.637-1.414 1.423-1.414h2.875c.377 0 .74.15 1.006.414.267.265.417.625.417 1v3.057c-.002.325.126.637.356.867.23.23.544.36.87.36h1.962a3.46 3.46 0 002.443-1 3.41 3.41 0 001.013-2.422V9.867c0-.735-.328-1.431-.895-1.902l-6.671-5.29a3.097 3.097 0 00-3.949.072L3.467 7.965A2.474 2.474 0 002.5 9.867v8.702C2.5 20.464 4.047 22 5.956 22h1.916c.68 0 1.231-.544 1.236-1.218l.027-.009z" />
                    </svg>
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="sidebar-link trending" href="#">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.835 12.007l.002.354c.012 1.404.096 2.657.242 3.451 0 .015.16.802.261 1.064.16.38.447.701.809.905a2 2 0 00.91.219c.249-.012.66-.137.954-.242l.244-.094c1.617-.642 4.707-2.74 5.891-4.024l.087-.09.39-.42c.245-.322.375-.715.375-1.138 0-.379-.116-.758-.347-1.064-.07-.099-.18-.226-.28-.334l-.379-.397c-1.305-1.321-4.129-3.175-5.593-3.79 0-.013-.91-.393-1.343-.407h-.057c-.665 0-1.286.379-1.603.991-.087.168-.17.496-.233.784l-.114.544c-.13.874-.216 2.216-.216 3.688zm-6.332-1.525C3.673 10.482 3 11.162 3 12a1.51 1.51 0 001.503 1.518l3.7-.328c.65 0 1.179-.532 1.179-1.19 0-.658-.528-1.191-1.18-1.191l-3.699-.327z" />
                    </svg>
                    My Courses
                </a>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
```